# cut column range sed/awk/cat

Tags: text-processing, awk, cat, cut

I'd like to cut a certain range of text (i.e. characters 17-63) repeatedly from a `*.txt` file, which is several thousand lines long.

One line looks like this:

```
<script>addRow("monatswerte_RR_00002_19140101_20061231_hist.zip","monatswerte_RR_00002_19140101_20061231_hist.zip",0,"12.3 kB","8/11/15, 5:18:00 PM");</script>
```

Can anyone suggest how to:

i. Cut this text range?

ii. Append it to another common string?

**Updated:**

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' all-files.txt > output.txt
```

Gives me a `.txt` file named `output.txt`. I then used

```
awk '{print "ftp://ftp-server.etc..." $0;}' output.txt > list.txt
```

To generate the final list of filenames needed for web-scraping.

Comment: normal way to cut columns is with cut ... cut -c17-64 file.txt ... does that not work?

Comment: Well, define a column ? Because you have <script>, addRow., parenthesis, </script> stuff like that. What exactly you need to extract in the lines ? What exactly you want to keep ? are you reffering to columns as those coma separated values inside parenthesis ?

Comment: @Serg I've updated the question for clarity..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was the same as Jeff Schaller's: `cut -c 17-64`. However that includes the closing quote, so you need `cut -c 17-63`

If you want the first quoted word and not every word is the same length, you can use awk: `awk -F\" '{print $2}' file.txt`